# Cursor jumps out when typing in input text field in Vue

Tags: html, vuejs2, vuex, v-for, v-model

I have this piece of code, which displays a list of features in an editable input field and text area. It gives the ability to the user to change the UI dynamically.

```
<div v-for="feature in features" :key="feature.name" class="relative mt-4 mb-4">
              <h3 class="text-md leading-6 font-medium text-color-700">
                Feature-{{feature.id + 1}}
              </h3>
                <div class="sm:col-span-6">
                    <div class="mt-1 flex rounded-md shadow-sm">
                        <input id="name" v-model="features[feature.id].name" type="text" name="name" class="flex-1 text-field-style block w-full min-w-0 text-xs" placeholder="heading" >
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="sm:col-span-6">
                    <div class="mt-1 flex rounded-md shadow-sm">
                        <textarea id="description" v-model="features[feature.id].description" placeholder="description" name="description" rows="3" class="block w-full text-xs text-field-style"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

In the UI, whenever I start typing in the input field, the cursor jumps out right after typing one letter. It is working fine in the text-area field. I am little new to Vue, so not able to figure out why this is happening.

`features` is an array of objects which is rendered elsewhere

```
  features: [
    {
      id: 0,
      name: 'Invite team members',
      description: 'Tempor tellus in aliquet eu et sit nulla tellus. Suspendisse est, molestie blandit quis ac. Lacus.',
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Notifications',
      description: 'Ornare donec rhoncus vitae nisl velit, neque, mauris dictum duis. Nibh urna non parturient.',
    }]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you using the same date to generate your elements in your `v-for` loop, as you use in your `v-model`. I guess that `features` is reactive data and therefore you having this trouble because of trying to manipulate it.

As you tagged `vuex` you should not manipulate data outside of your store. If you need to edit already existing data in a form, just provide a new object based on the current data of `features`:

```
myModelData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.features))
```

In this case `myModelData` data won´t be bound to `features`, so you can edit it in your inputs. After doing so, pass it to your store to update `features`. Note that if `features` changes while editing `myModelData`, `myModelData` won´t react to the change.